# How can you determine if a string has been updated/changed?

Tags: c#, .net

I cannot keep the original string in memory because it is too big.

```
var source = "some text";
var cache = source;
source = "some other text";
if(source != cache){
   // Updated, do something
}
```

Any idea how to find if the source string was updated/changed without comparing source and cache?

**Updated**, i have a found linked question
[Example to use a hashcode to detect if an element of a List<string> has changed C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759288/example-to-use-a-hashcode-to-detect-if-an-element-of-a-liststring-has-changed-c)

Comment: I don't understand what are you asking. Can you clarify ?

Comment: actually, it doesn't look like a question.

Comment: I can not parse your question, can you rephrase it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you could try making a hash of the 2 strings and compare those...

I hope this help...

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using a custom getter?

```
class SomeClass
{

    private bool m_MyStringUpdated;
    private String m_MyString;
    public String myString
    {
        get
        {
            return m_MyString;
        }
        set
        {
            m_MyString = value;
            m_MyStringUpdated = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can't keep the string a variable cache, then I'd say the best route is to utilize a collection with a key/value pair.  Something like `Dictionary<datetime, string>` where the key would be the last updated datetime stamp and string is the stored string.

Or you could use `Dictionary<bool, string>` where the key is a boolean of whether or not it is updated (true/false).  You will just need to remember to reset it to `false` after you have handled the instance of an updated string value.